# ReactiveUI Register Multiple Assemblies with Splat?

Tags: reactiveui, splat

Is it possible to register multiple assemblies containing modules of registrations,, using ReactiveUI/Splat?

Something like:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterAssemblies(typeof(CommonModule).Assembly, typeof(WindowsModule).Assembly));
```

Comment: What do you want to Register inside the Assemblies, your views?

Comment: Windows module would contain everything for Windows, including views and everything Windows-specific. Common module would contain general registrations (console stuff, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inbuilt

Two approaches.

You could use a similar approach to how rxui registers it platform stuff.

They have a interface where the registration happens. See https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI.Wpf/Registrations.cs for a example. You would just have to run the func logic yourself similar to

Other thing there is a auto method for splat the will register all items with the iviewfor called RegisterViewsForViewModels which is a mutator for the splat mutable container.

Comment: Also worth noting there are some proposals to simplify our DI integration https://github.com/reactiveui/rfcs/issues/14

Comment: And actually, making a PR for registering types in general is on my todo list. Particularly for Android where a constructor-created activity is useless. We have to do ‘var intent = new Intent(context: this, typeof(ActivityType)); StartActivity(intent);’

Comment: Mind marking it as the answer if you're happy with it. Thanks.